# Получение данных из базы по частям

Tags: php_pdo

Насколько я знаю у mysqli есть два варианта работы SELECT запросов: когда данные от базы отдаются сразу скопом, и когда кэш данных хранится в базе и отдается по частями. Напрямую mysqli не использовал - работал с классом-оболочкой вокруг этого модуля и не обращал внимания. Решил потыкаться с PDO - возникла сразу же проблема с получением большого количества данных - вылетает ошибка переполнения отведенного места скрипту. Мне хотелось бы знать, как можно реализовать получение данных из базы по частям. Если кто-то начнет предлагать альтернативы - сразу говорю, что о них я в курсе (самое простое: изменять логику так, что бы не работать с таким колличеством информации), поэтому хотелось бы получить ответ на вопрос с моими предпочтениями.

Comment: Вариант с выбором select * from somethink limit x,n где x = i*n и обработкой его в цикле вы расцениваете как альтернативу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне кажется что Вам поможет `setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_LAZY)` ?

Подробнее в [мануле](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.setfetchmode.php)